# Reinstall Grub on Fedora from live image

Tags: fedora, dual-boot, grub

After reading nearly every similar question, I can not get Grub to recognize my new Fedora install.

Previously, I was dual booting Windows and Arch. I have removed Arch and installed Fedora instead. However, I guess I have confused Grub in the process. When I boot after installing Fedora, I get a `grub-rescue` prompt. My guess is that Grub still sees the config from the Arch install.

I have tried booting Fedora from the live CD, mounting the root partition (`/dev/sda6` in my case; the boot partition is `/dev/sda5`) and running `grub2-install` to no success. The command wants a target or directory to be passed.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are all installs UEFI or all old BIOS. That might explain why you did not overwrite a grub installed in different boot mode. Most systems in lasst 10 years are UEFI and should have UEFI installs.

Comment: They should all be UEFI. I have been mounting `/dev/sda1` to `/boot/efi`.

Comment: If you really installed Fedora in UEFI mode, then probably it's just that its UEFI boot entry wasn't prioritized over the residual one of Arch. Do you know how to go your UEFI settings? Try to find out how and you can change the UEFI boot order there. And you can boot the Fedora live medium again (in UEFI mode) and share the output of `efibootmgr` (which can also be used to change UEFI boot order and even, remove residual UEFI boot entries).

Comment: Condensed `efibootmgr` output. What about the unknown device on the boot partition?

`BootCurrent: 0003
BootOrder: 2001,0002,0001,2002,2003
Boot0000* GRUB HD(1,GPT)/File(\EFI\GRUB\grubx64.efi)
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager HD(1,GPT)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager HD(1,GPT)/File(\EFI\GRUB\grubx64.efi)
Boot0003* USB HDD: SanDisk Cruzer Glide RC
Boot0004* Unknown Device:  HD(1,GPT)/File(\EFI\fedora\shim.efi) File(.䍒)
Boot0005* Fedora HD(1,GPT)/File(\EFI\fedora\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device RC`

Comment: If you can't edit your question, use a pastebin and leave the link as a comment. Anyway, it seems that the boot entry you want is `Boot0005` but it's not in the boot order for some reason. Try to have it as the first one in your boot order. (You can do it with `efibootmgr -o 0005`. I don't guarantee that it's perfectly safe though as some UEFI firmware is of really poor quality.) Also see the man page of `efibootmgr` for the details of `-o`.

Comment: I changed the boot order from the live media and the results did not save. I also changed the boot order after being `chroot`ed in Fedora. `efibootmgr` shows the order is correct, but order is not saved after reboot.

Comment: See if deleting the whole order with `-O` first (and reboot to the live medium again) makes any difference. (You don't need to bother chrooting for `efibootmgr` actions.)

Comment: I did this and the boot order reverts after reboot. The changes again are not saved.

Comment: No idea then. Some UEFI firmware just stinks. Try to delete all the entries, or even `chattr -i` and `rm` everything under `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/` maybe. (The latter would typically reset all your UEFI settings as well.) I do not guarantee these actions are safe on firmware that stinks though, and they might or might not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try one or both of these:

```
sudo dnf reinstall shim-* grub2-*
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

But of course, booting from a live image, you sill have to chroot to the proper root volume as well mount the proper boot volume.

-- http://rboci.blogspot.com/2021/04/updating-uefi-boot-record-on-fedora.html

Answer (score 0):

to reinstall Grub from a live image, you need to bind mount `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars`.

1. Mount root partition on `/mnt/root`.
2. Mount EFI boot partition: `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi`
3. Bind mount special partitions:

   ```bash
   mount -o bind /dev /mnt/root/dev
   mount -o bind /proc /mnt/root/proc
   mount -o bind /sys /mnt/root/sys
   mount -o bind /run /mnt/root/run
   mount -o bind /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /mnt/root/sys/firmware/efi/efivars
   ```
4. Chroot to the broken install: `chroot /mnt/root /usr/bin/bash`
5. Reinstall Grub: `sudo dnf reinstall shim-* grub2-*` (or any other rescue operations).

See [bruteforks comment @ Setting up chroot from a live image in Fedora. Regenerate grub2 for Fedora Gist](https://gist.github.com/Tamal/73e65bfb0e883e438310c5fe81c5de14?permalink_comment_id=4553369#gistcomment-4553369).